# Discord JS 12.5.3 messageUpdate have trouble

Tags: discord.js

i added messageUpdate for my bot's modlogs like this:

```
c.on("messageUpdate", function(oldMessage, newMessage) {
      if (oldMessage.channel.type !== "text") return;
      if (newMessage.channel.type !== "text") return;

      if (oldMessage.content === newMessage.content) return;
      send_log(
        c,
        oldMessage.guild,
        "YELLOW",
        "Message UPDATED",
        `
**Author : ** <@${newMessage.author.id}>
**Date : ** <t:${parseInt(newMessage.createdTimestamp / 1000)}:R>
**Channel : ** <#${newMessage.channel.id}>
**Orignal Message : **
\`\`\`
${oldMessage.content.replace(/`/g, "'")}
\`\`\`
**Updated Message : **
\`\`\`
${newMessage.content.replace(/`/g, "'")}
\`\`\``
      );
    });
```

it worked fine for a few minutes: [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poYGY.png)

then my bot got into exit status 1 because of this:

```
**Author : ** <@${newMessage.author.id}>
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/hibikibanmai-bot/events/client/logger.js:286:37)
```

Comment: Try console logging the value of `newMessage` before the place where the error happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe add:

```
if (!newMessage.author) return;
```